SwiftUI view in UIHostingVC inside UINavigationController: largeTitle not changing to inline
I have a SwiftUI View, that is a List. Embedded in a UIHostingController, itself embedded in FriendsViewController part of UINavigationController
When scrolling, there are 2 issues:

The title won't change to inline
The background is incorrect, the default UIKit behavior is expected

I basically tried everything I could, even changing the navBar appearance, but I was never able to reach the default (and good) UIKit behavior, which is:

Title will switch to inline when scrolling
Background of nav bar becomes vibrant

Details:

There is NO NavigationView nor NavigationStack in the SwiftUI View.

Any help will be much appreciated :-)!
Code
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: friendsView)
    self.addChild(hostingController)
    hostingController.didMove(toParent: self)
    self.view.addSubview(hostingController.view)
    
    hostingController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        hostingController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
        hostingController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor),
        hostingController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor),
        hostingController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
    ])
    
    configureNavigation()
}

private func configureNavigation() {
    // Navigation title
    self.title = "Friends"
    
    // Create UIBarButtonItems
    let symbolConfiguration = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(paletteColors: [.systemOrange, .systemBlue])
    let symbolImage = UIImage(systemName: "person.badge.plus", withConfiguration: symbolConfiguration)
    let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: symbolImage, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(addFriend))

    // Set the toolbar items
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton
}


I cannot reproduce on iOS 17.4. The nav bar works correctly. Please show a [mcve].

Apologies: I added a code sample + a bit more details.

So the trick is not to embed the UIHostingController as a child of another UIViewController. It prevents the scroll & title to work properly together.
